# How to raise events defined using Event Properties

Tags: c#, events, memory-management, event-handling

I am learning Events and Delegates & started with multiple events now. Just that the docs does not supply any information or code example to raising events defined in this manner.Below you can find a simple example

#### Sample Code

```
public class Person
    {
        private string _name;
        private string _phone;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set
            {
                _name = value;
            }
        }

        public string Phone
        {
            get { return _phone; }
            set
            {
                _phone = value;
            }
        }

        protected EventHandlerList EventDelegateCollection = new EventHandlerList();

        //define the event key
        static readonly object PhoneChangedEventKey = new object();
        public event EventHandler PhoneChanged
        {
            add
            {
                EventDelegateCollection.AddHandler(PhoneChangedEventKey, value);
            }
            remove
            {
                EventDelegateCollection.RemoveHandler(PhoneChangedEventKey, value);
            }
        }
    }
```

I would like to raise the event when the Phone number is set. if anything sounds funky and don't understand what i am talking about [see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edzehd2t%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

#### Update

I would like to clear some doubts here. There are Two ways you can actually subscribe and invoke the event handlers the classical pattern([as described here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/17sde2xt.aspx)) where the steps are

- Define the delegate that acts as signature for subscribed methods.
- Define the Event that delegates
- Define the method that raises the handlers
  `note:` above method creates field for every event hence consumes more memory [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0sx1bz6x.aspx)

Event Property is another way where you do below

- Define a object that acts as Key to a event
- Define a method to add and remove handlers for the event from the event invocation list
- Raise the event by determining event handlers based on event key

Comment: This MSDN link describes raising the event: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9aackb16%28v=VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to dispatch events in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448487/how-to-dispatch-events-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @HenkHolterman i repeat that is classical way to invoke event handlers, Event Properties is another way look here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8843a9ch.aspx

Comment: That page also lists the `OnMouseDown()` and `OnMouseUp()` methods so what is your exact question then?

Comment: @HenkHolterman thank you, solved the question myself and code is available below.

Comment: @Anyone who wanted to close the question, please see the update of why this question differs from other related questions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how you should actually raise it

#### Code

```
public class Person
{
    private string _name;
    private string _phone;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
        }
    }

    public string Phone
    {
        get { return _phone; }
        set
        {
            _phone = value;
            //Invoke the Handlers now
            OnPhoneChanged();
        }
    }

    protected EventHandlerList EventDelegateCollection = new EventHandlerList();
    static readonly object PhoneChangedEventKey = new object();
    public event EventHandler PhoneChanged
    {
        add
        {
            EventDelegateCollection.AddHandler(PhoneChangedEventKey, value);
        }
        remove
        {
            EventDelegateCollection.RemoveHandler(PhoneChangedEventKey, value);
        }
    }

    private void OnPhoneChanged()
    {
        EventHandler subscribedDelegates = (EventHandler)this.EventDelegateCollection[PhoneChangedEventKey];
        subscribedDelegates(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to read [Delegates and Events in C#](http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_delegates_and_events.html). The code below is what you want.

```
public class Person
{
    public event EventHandler<string> PhoneNumberChanged;

    private string _name;
    private string _phone;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
        }
    }

    public string Phone
    {
        get { return _phone; }
        set
        {
            _phone = value;

            if (this.PhoneNumberChanged != null)
            {
                this.PhoneNumberChanged(this._phone);
            }
        }
    }
}
```