# How is this code in FormsAuthenticationModule supposed to work?

Tags: c#, .net, iis, .net-4.0

I'm reading .NET4 sources (they can be downloaded for research freely) and I found something strange in the implementation of `System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule`.

The class is declared like this:

```
public sealed class FormsAuthenticationModule : IHttpModule
```

where `IHttpModule` has two methods - `Init()` and `Dispose()`.

Inside `OnEnter()` there're these lines:

```
// Step 2: Call OnAuthenticate virtual method to create 
//    an IPrincipal for this request
OnAuthenticate( new FormsAuthenticationEventArgs(context) );
```

where `OnAuthenticate()` is declared like this:

```
// OnAuthenticate: Forms Authentication modules can override 
//             this method to create a Forms IPrincipal object from
//             a WindowsIdentity 
private void OnAuthenticate(FormsAuthenticationEventArgs e) {
```

Now the class is `sealed`, so it's impossible to inherit from. Also `OnAuthenticate()` is not `virtual` so I don't see how it could have been overridden anyway.

So it looks like these comments are just outdated and overriding `OnAuthenticate()` is no longer possible.

Did I get anything wrong? Could this code possibly allow overriding `OnAuthenticate()`?

Comment: AFAIU This class is sealed from the very [beginning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthenticationmodule(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: From the name and params it follows that this is an ['event trigger'](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2448530/60761), they should normally be virtual. That of course conflicts with sealed. Worst case a class could subscribe to its own events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work. It's simply incorrect documentation. Not a first for MS. For example, I notified MS about this back in version 1.1 of the .NET Framework and here we are at 4.5 and there documentation is still totally misleading: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7he0a7s1.aspx

Notice the "Notes to Inheritors" section. How is someone supposed to derive a class from BindingManagerBase when it contains several `internal abstract` properties and methods? And yet there are several places in the documentation for BindingManagerBase and CurrencyManager that have "Notes to Inheritors"...

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but the only way is to implement an FormsAuthenticate_OnAuthenticate event in your Global.asax. When you set e.Context.User to a value, it prevents the internal code from executing. It's a little clunky.